# Facebook SDK + Google SDK: The frame being accessed set 'document.domain' to 'facebook.com'

Tags: google-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-plus

I am incorporating the google javascript client library on my page.  I also have the Facebook javascript SDK installed.  When I launch the google authentication, it authenticates fine, but when it calls back, I get a same origin error in chrome.  It appears as though it is trying to call back to the Facebook helper frame as opposed to the Google helper frame.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: GlobalSettings.google_client_id, scope: scopes, immediate: false, authuser:-1}, this._validateGoogle);
```

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=17#channel=f141ef255c&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fpicolocal.com&channel_path=%2Fassets%2Fchannel.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df356553d18%26 from frame with URL https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?zt=ChR3VkFzQjdTLVM1M214bmQybTlURRIfc2pVUmM4YXkwc0lVdUpKVm5MNDlDYzlxUVliSGRnSQ%E2%88%99APsBz4gAAAAAUL1kGm5n1rNtBr7JzWO79BsCrWR3JQ0F&from_login=0&hl=en&as=fc48d65d9e4aad8&pli=1&authuser=0. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.
>
> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=17#channel=f2a52e49dc&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fpicolocal.com&channel_path=%2Fassets%2Fchannel.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df2ce0c29cc%26 from frame with URL https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?zt=ChRHWUYwOTVFck5wQUZGM1dfMFI2chIfUWhFRmJaWFlJdzBadUpKVm5MNDlDYzlnc1dISGRnSQ%E2%88%99APsBz4gAAAAAUL1fbOLmx90l39zNA-9tUFG8ghM-l8qG&from_login=0&hl=en&as=78294d299ef41f66&pli=1&authuser=1. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a very detailed guide on how to incorporate the Facebook SDK & Google+ Sign-In over at https://developers.google.com/+/best-practices/facebook. You should use [gapi.auth.signIn()](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference#javascript_api) instead of `gapi.auth.authorize()`.